# what is 'proxy.mycompany1.local'

Tags: java, proxy

I just started working in Java networking protocols. I am trying to connect to the internet using my proxy server. When I see the post at 'https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/net_poxy.htm', they set the http.proxyHost property to 'proxy.mycompany1.local'. I know I can set this to my proxy server IP, but I am curious to know why my program still works, even though I set it to some random string like "abcd".

A. What does 'proxy.mycompany1.local" stand for?

B. How come my program works, even though I set the http.proxyHost" to "abcd"?

Following is my working program:

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.ProxySelector;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;

public class TestProxy {
    public static void main(String s[]) throws Exception {
        try {

            System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "abcd");
            System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");

            URL u = new URL("http://www.google.com");
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            System.out.println(con.getResponseCode() + " : " + con.getResponseMessage());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(false);
        }
        Proxy proxy = (Proxy) ProxySelector.getDefault().select(new URI("http://www.google.com")).iterator().next();
        System.out.println("proxy Type : " + proxy.type());
        InetSocketAddress addr = (InetSocketAddress) proxy.address();
        if (addr == null) {
            System.out.println("No Proxy");
        } else {
            System.out.println("proxy hostname : " + addr.getHostName());
            System.out.println("proxy port : " + addr.getPort());
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
200 : OK
proxy Type : HTTP
proxy hostname : abcd
proxy port : 8080
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, according [System Properties tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

> Warning: Changing system properties is potentially dangerous and
>   should be done with discretion. Many system properties are not reread
>   after start-up and are there for informational purposes. Changing some
>   properties may have unexpected side-effects.

And my experience say you can get unpleasant issues on your system when you change `*.proxyHost`  properties. So I highly wouldn't recommend you to change system properties for this task.

Much better use something like:

```
//Proxy instance, proxy ip = 127.0.0.1 with port 8080
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8080));
conn = new URL(urlString).openConnection(proxy);
```

and authorisation on proxy:

```
Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("user",
                    "mypassword".toCharArray());
        }
    };
    Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);
```

Now return to main questions:

**A.** 'proxy.mycompany1.local" is just example. You can use any hostname

**B.** Class URL uses  java.net.PlainSocketImpl class via Socket. It tries to resolve proxy hostname `'abcd'`, swallow error and go to google directly. Just try to play with this code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class RequestURI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int port = 8181;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
//            System.getProperties().setProperty("http.proxyHost", "abcd");
//            System.getProperties().setProperty("http.proxyPort", Integer.toString(port));

            URL url = new URL("http://google.com");
            HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            int resp = uc.getResponseCode();
            if (resp != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed: Fragment is being passed as part of the RequestURI");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Run time in ms ="+ (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
    }
}
```

You can see run time is bigger when you uncomment section with `setProperty`. Unsuccessful attempt to resolve hostname increases execution time.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `proxy.mycompany1.local` is just a host name, it is a sample, it is nothing special.

I tried your code in a non proxied network, and it worked as you described. I guess that `url.openConnection()` method ignores proxy settings, because if you manage your own proxy and use `url.openConnection(proxy)`, then it fails with a `java.net.UnknownHostException`.

Here you are with a piece of code that fails:

```
SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress("abcd", 8080);
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, addr);
URL url = new URL("http://google.com");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(proxy);
InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
in.close();
```

You can read more about [Java Networking and Proxies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html).